# Azure Pipelines CI Not firing

Tags: github, azure-devops, continuous-integration

My organization recently changed from using personal GitHub accounts to using GitHub Enterprise Managed Users. Since that change our pipeline continuous integration (in Azure Devops) has stopped working. We can still run the builds manually without issue, but it isn't even attempting to start the builds automatically. I've created new personal access tokens for the pipelines, but that hasn't fixed the continuous integration. Does anyone have any suggestions on what I should look at to get this working again?

Comment: If the pipelines where using a service connection to GitHub, they where created with a service account / GitHub App connection that no longer has access, so my guess is that you need to recreate it. See @jessehouwing 's comment below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wound up fixing this by going to the repository in Git Hub, go to settings on the repository, and then to Web Hooks. In there, the hook that Azure Pipelines uses had an error on it because when our tech group migrated the repo they did not bring the secret over. To fix it I just had to delete the web hook, go to the pipeline and a button appeared to restore the connection.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of relying on user-authenticates service connections between GitHub and Azure Pipelines, I recommend switching over go the Github App for Azure Pipelines to control what repositories Azure Pipelines can access:

https://github.com/apps/azure-pipelines

That will drastically simplify access maintenance between GitHub and Azure Pipelines and will break the reliance on personal or enterprise managed accounts.

Comment: Thank you for this suggestion. I'll look into this to see if this will be something good to migrate toward.